# Using words used as words: Why am I confusing myself?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, terminology, italics

> Humans, naturally, prefer *simple* over *complex*.

I would think that in the above sentence, both *simple* and *complex* are words used as words. (Though, perhaps, not as clear as it is in the preceding sentence.) Yet, I still feel confused. The source of my confusion is that I would not think of italicizing *red* and *green* in the following sentence:

> I prefer red over green.

Another example:

> The scientific distinction between *simple* and *complex* has long
>   been blurred.

versus

> The scientific distinction between blue and green is [whatever].

In the first example I feel like I should italicize, but not in the second example.

In what ways am I confusing myself?

Comment: I think you only need to italicise (or quote) if you are saying that people prefer the word “simple” over the word “complex” (which seems unlikely).

Comment: Could it be that you feel *red* and *green* designate properties have objectively, whereas *simple* and *complex* designate properties that we might or might not want to ascribe to them, depending on our interests, capacities etc?

Comment: If so I understand the desire to italicise, but I disagree with you about *red* and *green*.

Comment: None of your examples appear to be using word as words at all. They are being used as syntactical components of the surrounding text. As I also see no reason for the words to be emphasized (as in speech), the use of italics appears wrong in *all* of the examples.

Comment: @Jason I have never heard of *syntactical components* thing. Can you elaborate more (especially as to how one differentiates between using words as words and as syntactical components without confusing himself), or direct me to a source?

Comment: Think of words as words as *meta*. They are in the sentence, but they are not fully participating in it. *The Chicago Manual of Style* says "when a word or term is not used functionally but is referred to as the word or term itself, it is either italicized or enclosed in quotation marks." It's the difference between "*I don't like the word* agree," and *I agree with you.* In the first sentence, the word itself is set off as the *object* of the sentence. In the second, it's just a normal part of an everyday sentence, and has no meaning *removed from* the sentence.

Comment: In hindsight, I misspoke by implying that words as words are not syntactical components. They are. But they are a different type of component—or, as objects, they refer to *themselves* rather than to the things they would otherwise *represent*.

Comment: I think you are making things too *complex*.  There is no need to italicize *simple* words such as those in your first example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the main discussion of "words used as words" in *The Chicago Manual of Style*, 16th edition (2010):

> **7.58 *Words and phrases used as words*.** When a word or term is not used functionally but is referred to as the word or term itself, it is either italicized or enclosed in quotation marks. ...
>
> > [Example:] The term *critical mass* is more often used metaphorically than literally.
> >
> > [Example:] What is meant by *neurobotics*?

Chicago's discussion indicates that when a word is being used as a word in the narrow sense, the sentence would continue to convey the writer's intended meaning if you added "the word" in front of the word being used as a word. Thus, in Chicago's second example above, it would make perfect sense to insert "the word" before *neurobotics*:

> What is meant by the word *neurobotics*?

Pretty straightforward so far, right? Now let's apply it to the first three examples that you raise. First:

> Humans, naturally, prefer *simple* over *complex*.

If the words *simple* and *complex* were being used as words, it would make sense to say this:

> Humans, naturally, prefer the word *simple* over the word *complex*.

But that doesn't sound right. There is no reason to suppose that humans naturally prefer the word *simple* over the word *complex* insofar as they are merely words. Why should they?

So what's going on with the original sentence? Well, I'd say that the intention of that original sentence is to claim that people prefer simple things over complex things. That is, the implied (but absent) element in the original sentence isn't "the word" (twice) but "things" (twice):

> Humans, naturally, prefer simple things over complex things.

This version of the sentence makes sense—and it establishes pretty clearly that *simple* and *complex* weren't being used as words in the original sentence. For that reason, Chicago wouldn't endorse italicizing them.

Now let's look at the second example in your question:

> I prefer *red* over *green*.

If *red* and *green* were words used as words, the sentence would still express the writer's original meaning if we reworded it as follows:

> I prefer the word *red* over the word *green*.

But it seems far more likely that the writer intended to use the words as colors, not as words. That is:

> I prefer the color red over the color green.

And if that was the writer's intention, *red* and *green* in the original sentence were not being used as words.

Your third example raises a somewhat more challenging issue: how do we handle words used as concepts? Here is the example:

> The scientific distinction between *simple* and *complex* has long been blurred.

If we apply our word-used-as-word test to this form of the sentence, the result isn't very satisfactory:

> The scientific distinction between the word *simple* and the word *complex* has long been blurred.

The problem is that the blurry scientific distinction isn't between two words—one six letters long and one seven letters long. It's between two problematic concepts:

> The scientific distinction between the concept of simple and the concept of complex has long been blurred.

or two fundamental meanings:

> The scientific distinction between the fundamental meaning of simple and the fundamental meaning of complex has long been blurred.

In my view, *simple* in the phrase "the concept of simple" isn't a word used as a word; rather, it's a word used to convey a particular idea that we've given the name *simple* to. I would therefore not italicize *simple* and *complex* in that form of the sentence. In fact, we might very well interpret the scientific dispute in a vulgarly materialistic way, as follows:

> The scientific distinction between simple things and complex things has long been blurred.

In that case, we're clearly not dealing with the words *simple* and *complex* used as words.

But the version of the sentence involving "the meaning of simple" seems different. There, we are just one crucial interpretive step from fully satisfying the word-used-as-word condition—and once again that step consists of adding "the word" to the revised sentence (twice):

> The scientific distinction between the fundamental meaning of the word *simple* and the fundamental meaning of the word *complex* has long been blurred.

What do you know—we're back to making a statement about the meaning of two words used as words!

These results demonstrate that how you interpret a bare-bones sentence can sometimes make the difference between whether you conclude that certain words in it are being used as words (in the Chicago sense) or not.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to referring to the use/mention distinction. However, unless you are saying that people prefer the *word* "simple to the *word* complex, your first example is an example of use, not mention. Your third example is more fuzzy, as you can be saying that the actual concepts of simplicity and complexity don't have clear boundaries (use) or that the distinction between when the word "simplicity" should be used and the word "complexity" should be used, that would be mention.